# Search bar error: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Post' / Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement search in Django. When I enter something into the search, I get an error: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Post'.

> app view

```
def searchbar(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    searched = request.Post["searched"]
    students = Q(pk__contains=searched) | Q(first_name__contains=searched) | Q(last_name__contains=searched)
    return render(request, template_name='searchbar.html', context={"searched": searched, "students": students})
else:
    return render(request, template_name='searchbar.html', context={})
```

> template

```
    {% extends "index.html" %}

   {% block content %}
  <center>
  {% if searched %}
      <h1>You search for {{ searched }}</h1>
      <br/>
      {% for student in students %}
          {{ student.first_name }} {{ student.last_name }}<br/>
      {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
      <h1>Nothing to search</h1>
  {% endif %}


  </center>
{% endblock %}
```

Tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: It is `request.POST`, not `request.Post`.

Answer (score 1):

As Sir [@WillemVanOnsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) stated in above comment:

> It is `request.POST` not <s>`request.Post`</s>.